# Alternate color in <tr> not working for dynamic table

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the following XML :

```
 <discrepancyModel>
     <MissingSuppliers isMissingSuppliersCheckApplied="true">
            <SnsCode value="str1234" mi="GRAA350RR" syst="29" subsys="2"
    subsubsys="1" assy="XX" />
            <SnsCode value="str1234" mi="GRAA350RR" syst="29" subsys="2"
    subsubsys="3" assy="XX" />
            <SnsCode value="str1234" mi="TRENTXWB" syst="28" subsys="1"
    subsubsys="1" assy="XX" />
            <SnsCode value="str1234" mi="TRENTXWB" syst="29" subsys="1"
    subsubsys="1" assy="57" />
            <SnsCode value="str1234" mi="TRENTXWC" syst="29" subsys="1"
    subsubsys="1" assy="58" />
            <SnsCode value="str1234" mi="TRENTXWD" syst="29" subsys="1"
    subsubsys="1" assy="58" />
        </MissingSuppliers>
    </discrepancyModel>
```

The expected output is:

Here I have to display the information of each SNSCODE in a table row. If 2 or more SNSCODE have the same value of @mi, then SNSCODE is written only once but its has multiple rows in front of it (i.e 1st column is combined)

The main problem where I am stuck is that i want alternate colors for rows but i am not able to achieve that. I have seen all earlier answers but they do not solve my problem.

I have the following xslt code :

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Name (MI)</th>
    <th>systemCode</th>
    <th>subSystemCode</th>
    <th>subSubSystemCode</th>
    <th>assyCode</th>
  </tr>
  <xsl:for-each select="//SnsCode">
    <xsl:variable name="tmp">
      <xsl:value-of select="./@mi" />
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:if test="generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('stvalkey',$tmp)[1])">
      <xsl:variable name="miNumber" select="count(key('stvalkey',$tmp))" />
      <xsl:for-each select="//SnsCode[@mi=$tmp]">
        <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::SnsCode)" />
        <tr>
          <xsl:attribute name="class">
            <xsl:if test="position() mod 2 = 0">
              <xsl:value-of select="'odd'" />
            </xsl:if>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:if test="position()=1">
            <td>
              <xsl:attribute name="rowspan">
                <xsl:value-of select="$miNumber" />
              </xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:value-of select="$tmp" />
            </td>
          </xsl:if>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="./@syst" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="./@subsys" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="./@subsubsys" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="./@assy" />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
</table>
```

This code used for coloring is:

```
 <xsl:attribute name="class">
   <xsl:if test="position() mod 2 = 0">
     <xsl:value-of select="'odd'"/>
   </xsl:if>
 </xsl:attribute>
```

The problem with this is , if i use this code inside the loop, it does not color the whole row, it colors only 2nd row within a mi value.

On the other hand, if use this code outside the loop, then i do not get the position of elements as 1,2,3,4....but i get values as 1,3,5,6 because there are 2 occurences for 1st value and 2 occurence for 2nd value and so on.

Can anyone suggest how to do the coloring in this case ?

Comment: The expected output is missing. Could you check, please?

Comment: I was unable to put the image for expected output..so its missing..

Comment: I was unable to put the image for expected output..so its missing.

For the given XML, expected output is :
4 rows , with GRAA350RR, TRENTXWB,TRENTXWC, TRENTXWD in column 1.
Now for each of these values, we have multiple sub rows, depending on number of occurrence of SNSCODE with same @mi.
out of 4 rows, i want to color 2nd and 4th row i.e the ones starting with TRENTXWB and TRENTXWD.

The usual coloring Code in XSL takes the position of the ELEMENTS in the XML but i want the position for <TR> that is displayed. I hope my question and expected output is clear now.

Comment: @user2967621 You really need to figure out how to attach an image of what you want to see if you expect anyone to help.

Comment: Could you include the definition of the key used in your XSLT, please?

Comment: Ok. I guess you're using Muenchian Grouping with `<xsl:key name="stvalkey" match="//SnsCode" use="@mi"/>`. Correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following XSLT uses the overall structure given in the question. However, instead of using the `position()` of the context to determine the odd table rows it defines a variable `group_index` which determines how many groups precede the current group.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:key name="stvalkey" match="//SnsCode" use="@mi"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">

    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <th>Name (MI)</th>
        <th>systemCode</th>
        <th>subSystemCode</th>
        <th>subSubSystemCode</th>
        <th>assyCode</th>
      </tr>

      <xsl:for-each select="//SnsCode">

        <xsl:variable name="tmp" >
          <xsl:value-of select="./@mi"/>
        </xsl:variable>


        <xsl:if test="generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('stvalkey',$tmp)[1])">

          <xsl:variable name="group_index" select="count(preceding-sibling::SnsCode[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('stvalkey',@mi)[1])])"/>

          <xsl:variable name="miNumber" select="count(key('stvalkey',$tmp))" />

          <xsl:for-each select="//SnsCode[@mi=$tmp]">    
            <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::SnsCode)"/>
            <tr> 
              <xsl:attribute name="style">
                <xsl:if test="$group_index mod 2 = 0">
                  <xsl:value-of select="'background-color:yellow;'"/>
                </xsl:if>
              </xsl:attribute>     
              <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                <td>
                  <xsl:attribute name="rowspan">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$miNumber" />    
                  </xsl:attribute>
                  <xsl:value-of select="$tmp" />
                </td>
              </xsl:if>

              <td><xsl:value-of select="./@syst" /></td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="./@subsys" /></td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="./@subsubsys" /></td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="./@assy" /></td>
            </tr>

          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>  
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

resulting in this HTML output

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Name (MI)</th>
    <th>systemCode</th>
    <th>subSystemCode</th>
    <th>subSubSystemCode</th>
    <th>assyCode</th>
  </tr>0<tr style="background-color:yellow;">
    <td rowspan="2">GRAA350RR</td>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>XX</td>
  </tr>1<tr style="background-color:yellow;">
    <td>29</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>XX</td>
  </tr>2<tr style="">
    <td rowspan="2">TRENTXWB</td>
    <td>28</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>XX</td>
  </tr>3<tr style="">
    <td>29</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>57</td>
  </tr>4<tr style="background-color:yellow;">
    <td rowspan="1">TRENTXWC</td>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>58</td>
  </tr>5<tr style="">
    <td rowspan="1">TRENTXWD</td>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>58</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Notes:

- The key definition was added to make the XSLT work.
- The CSS class definition `odd` was replaced by an inline definition to make the coloring visible in the resulting HTML page.

Comment: Thans a lot **Marcus Rickert** and **Ian Roberts** for your answers.
The solution provided by Marcus works perfectly for my data. Instead of using the position() function, its better to use group index for counting keys for accurate results. This approach is not available anywhere else on net so i really appreciate your answer.
@Ian : Thanx for providing an alternate way. But the use of position() does not give the exact results in certain cases.

Comment: Could you pick your primary answer then? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If it's always the case that multiple records with the same `@mi` are adjacent in the source XML then you don't need the two nested levels of `for-each`, you could just do all the work in one `for-each` and use the key to deal with the first column:

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Name (MI)</th>
    <th>systemCode</th>
    <th>subSystemCode</th>
    <th>subSubSystemCode</th>
    <th>assyCode</th>
  </tr>
  <xsl:for-each select="//SnsCode">
    <xsl:variable name="tmp" select="@mi" />
    <xsl:variable name="miNumber" select="count(key('stvalkey',$tmp))" />
    <tr>
      <xsl:attribute name="class">
        <xsl:if test="position() mod 2 = 0">odd</xsl:if>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:if test="generate-id() = generate-id(key('stvalkey', $tmp)[1])">
        <td>
          <xsl:attribute name="rowspan">
            <xsl:value-of select="$miNumber" />
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:value-of select="$tmp" />
        </td>
      </xsl:if>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="./@syst" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="./@subsys" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="./@subsubsys" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="./@assy" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:for-each>
</table>
```

Now you only have one `for-each` the `position()` will give you the right value each time.